# form displaying in controller popup

Tags: laravel-5

i make form that i want to link in with controller called companies controller but i add form code inside the list it show the whole code ink the web page

```
<li>
    <a href="#" onclick="
        var result = confirm('are you sure you want to delete this project?');
        if(result){
            event.preventDefault();
            document.getElementById('delete-form').submit();
        }
    ">
        Delete
    </a>
    <form id="delete-form" action="{{ route('companies.destroy',[$company->id]) }}" method="post"  style="display:none;">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    </form>
</li>
```

in the web page only the delete should visible in the section not other part of the code

Comment: now this code is display in web page after reload     Delete "="" style="display:none;">

Answer (score 0):

first of all, separate your code of javascript from html so that it be understandable and also easy to debug. try this:

```
<li>
    <a href="#" onclick="delete()">Delete</a>
    <form id="delete-form" action="{{ route('companies.destroy',[$company->id]) }}" method="post"  style="display:none;">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    </form>
</li>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function delete()
    {
        var result = confirm('are you sure you want to delete this project?');
        if(result){
            event.preventDefault();
            document.getElementById('delete-form').submit();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Found some typos which I corrected, maybe that was the issue. Also, you could very well send an ajax instead of submitting a hidden form, just an idea.